# Outlook 2007 Offline Testing

Tags: testing, plugins, outlook, offline

I am developing a plugin for Outlook 2007 that I want to install on my company's email server.  Unfortunately I don't have administrative rights (yet) on that server, so I will be developing the plugin on my laptop.  I would like to configure Outlook to run without an internet connection, on my laptop (Vista) and be able to send and receive test emails to myself.

Google yields nothing--is there a way to do it?  I thought perhaps setting up an email server on my laptop and having Outlook point to that with some kind of dummy email address, but my knowledge in the area isn't sufficient.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is there is a solution that provides exactly this, and it's called [MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me/). It'll allow you to SMTP out, POP in and even has a nice management application to preview the mail passing through.

The bad news is it's a [ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/) application, which might be a rather large hurdle to take if you don't have any experience running ruby applications on Windows.

Comment: Thanks man, this looks like it would do the trick for half of what I want.  Would it send emails back to myself, though, if I addressed myself?  On another note, I believe I found something fairly workable for my purposes.  Since I am developing the Plugin to register Send events and "Unread" status loss on incoming emails, I rigged it by giving it totally fake server info.  Outlook lets me make an account, and "send" emails (with the corresponding event).  They never leave my Outbox, but that works.  I can also drag emails from the Outbox into my Inbox and mark them as Unread.  But thanks.

Comment: It's both SMTP and POP. The POP bit will return _every_ email you send it through SMTP. Your workaround sounds good, but you'll probably still need pop (or emulation) if you want to work on the 'incoming mails' check.